# cURL PUT following a redirect

Tags: curl, put

I have a url that is shortened using google firebase due to system constraints. I need to be able to do both curl PUT and GET commands to it. The url shortener ends up doing redirects which is where I belive my problems occur. I got GET to work using the -L flag.

```
curl -X GET -L "http://myshorturl.com/hostedfile" --output GET.csv
```

However I still can't get PUT to work

```
curl -X PUT -L "http://myshorturl.com/hostedfile" --upload-file PUT.csv
```

gives me an error

> Error 405 (Not Found)

this seems to mean that PUT isn't allowed but I know my endpoint does allow as when I do the same thing without shortening the url everything works fine.

```
curl -X PUT -L "http://mymuchlongerurl.com/hostedfile" --upload-file PUT.csv
```

Any ideas on how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, when PUT and POST methods are requested to the shortener URL, the error occurs, while for GET method, the request works fine using the option `-L`. So as a workaround of PUT request using the shortener URL, how about this?

#### Modified curl command:

```
curl -X PUT -L `curl -D - "http://myshorturl.com/hostedfile" | awk '/Location/ {print $NF}'` --upload-file PUT.csv
```

- `curl -D - "http://myshorturl.com/hostedfile"` retrieves the information of the redirect.

  - `-` of `-D -` means the result is displayed to stdout.
- `curl -D - "http://myshorturl.com/hostedfile" | awk '/Location/ {print $NF}'` retrieves the redirected URL.
- In your case, `-L` of the modified curl command might not be required. But I could't test it. I'm sorry for this.

#### Reference:

- [Option: -D](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-D)

If this was not the workaround you want and this didn't work, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I am still new to the command line and all the different commands I can utilize. What ended up working is 
curl -X PUT --upload-file PUT.csv -D - "http://myshorturl/hostedfile" | awk '/Location/ {print $NF}'

Comment: @DTATSO Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.